# How do I register inputs only if they have value with React-form-hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

As of right now my code registers all inputs, whether or not they have any value. How can I change my code so it only registers inputs only when there is value?

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      
      <input {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })} />
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setValue`. And then add s function that keeps track of any changes in the input field. And if there are any value it also checks that its not only whitespace.

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors }, setValue } = useForm();
  
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    // Check if the input value is not empty
    if (value.trim() !== "") {
      // Register the input with the provided name and set the value
      setValue(name, value);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input defaultValue="test" {...register("example")} />
      
      <input
        {...register("exampleRequired", { required: true })}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```